# Difference of nearest-neighbour clustering and K-nearest neighbour clustering

Tags: r, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

we're two students working on a seminar paper (topic: Marketing in the Age of Big Data) where we have to conduct a cluster analysis by using nearest neighbour clustering. unfortunately, we cannot differentiate between nearest neighbour clustering and K-nearest neighbours. At first of all we thought that it is the same just called different. After we've read many papers where it is said that KNN is a supervised machine learning algorithm, while our professor said that the nearest neighbour is an unsupervised algorithm we recognised that there must be a difference. There are a lot of different declarations on the internet, why we are confused now.

Hopefully, someone can help us to solve the understanding problems.

Many thanks in advance and many greetings.

Comment: This really isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about statistical methods, you should ask them at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic, or [datascience.se].

Comment: Already answered on Cross Validated [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56500/what-are-the-main-differences-between-k-means-and-k-nearest-neighbours][1]

Comment: nearest-neighbour clustering and k-nearest neigbour clustering. (Not K-means clustering). :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Nearest Neighbour" is merely "k Nearest Neighbours" with `k=1`.

What may be confusing is that "nearest neighbour" is also applicable to both supervised and unsupervised clustering.  In the supervised case, a "new", unclassified element is assigned to the same class as the nearest neighbour (or the mode of the nearest `k` neighbours).

In the unsupervised case, we generally apply "hierarchical clustering": take the two points with the least distance between them; declare a new class to contain the two points.

Now iterate through the distances, smallest to largest; if neither point is yet in a class, make a new class to contain them; if one point is already in a class, then add the other point to that class; if both points are in classes, then merge the classes.  Continue this process until you have the desired quantity of classes.

Note: when you add a point to a class, remove (from your iteration list) the distances from that point to other class members.  When you merge classes, remove all the distances between points that used to be in opposite classes.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Nearest neighbor algorithm basically returns the training example which is at the least distance from the given test sample. k-Nearest neighbor returns k(a positive integer) training examples at least distance from given test sample.